# "beforeShowDay" Not working for given Condition

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jquery-ui-datepicker

i want to enable only "friday" in datepicker.

```
 $(".input-monthpicker").datepicker({
             format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
            autoclose: true,
                //startDate: new Date(),
                beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                    return [date.getDay == 5]
                }
            });
```

am trying this simple code but not working \n
NOTE: this field inside jqgrid column \n
please find what is an issue

Comment: As you're using [tag:jqgrid], you'll need to hook into the grid events to run your code after the grid/table has been rendered.  See: http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events

Comment: Please can you share some code snippet

Comment: You can look into the demos in  [particular example](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/edit_add_delete/dialogs_edit_controls/index.html) . All the deomos can be found [here](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/)